# Verification of Stokes’ theorem for closed path and surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, curl

I am having trouble with the follow problem about Stoke's theorem:

Assume the vector field $A= <3x^2y^3,−x^3y^2>$
Verify Stoke's theorem for the closed path around the triangle with vertices (1,1) (2,1) (2,2) by:

a.) Finding $∮A·dl$

b.) Evaluating $∫∫(∇×A)·dS$

I have attempted to solve using both methods but have ended up with differing answers. for part A, I parametrized the path between $<t,1>,<2,t>, <t,t>$ for the triangle, and ended up with three seperate integrals, $∫ 3t^2dt + ∫ 3t^5dt+ ∫ -8t^2dt$, and evaluated them from (2,1) and got the answer as $-8.33$

For part B, I found the curl, $(∇×A)$ to be $-12x^2y^2$ and evaluated the integral $∫∫(-12x^2y^2)dxdy$ from (2,1), (2,1), but got the answer as $-65.3$

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: It would be nice if you put limits on your various integrals. Otherwise there's no way to tell what you've actually done. Come to think of it, where did you get the functions you integrated in the second two line integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stokes' theorem for a region $R$ is equivalent to Green's theorem in the plane, so that we need to show

$$\oint_C(Mdx+Ndy)=\iint_R\Big(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\Big)dxdy$$

where $R$ is the region bounded by the triangle with vertices $(1,1)$, $(2,1)$ and $(2,2)$; $C$ is the boundary of $R$. Here, $M=3x^2y^3$ and $N=−x^3y^2$.

Along the line from $(1,1)$ to $(2,1)$, $y=1$ ($dy=0$) and $x$ varies from $1$ to $2$ so that

$$\int_{C_1}(Mdx+Ndy)=\int_1^23x^2dy=7.$$

Along the line from $(2,1)$ to $(2,2)$, $x=2$ and $y$ varies from $1$ to $2$:

$$\int_{C_2}(Mdx+Ndy)=-8\int_1^2y^2dy=-\frac{56}{3}.$$

Along the line from $(2,2)$ to $(1,1)$, $x=y$ so that

$$\int_{C_3}(Mdx+Ndy)=\int_2^12x^5dx=-\frac{63}{3}.$$

Therefore,

$$\oint_C(Mdx+Ndy)=-\frac{98}{3}.$$

Also, the region $R$ bounded by the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}$ of the region bounded by the square with adjacent sides $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that

$$\iint_R\Big(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\Big)dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2\int_1^2-12x^2y^2dxdy=-\frac{98}{3}.$$